# Is there any way to print k integers from m to n circularly in python?

Tags: python

Is there any way to print k integers from m to n in circular manner in python

```py
n,m,k=map(int, input().split())

C=0

for i in range(n,m):
     print (i, end='')
     c=c+1
     if c>k:
       break
```

This is what i have tried. 
But the actual input and output is:

```
2 5 15
2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Input:2 5 15  output:2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4

Comment: Isn't that the same as your actual output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.cycle(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

> Which makes an iterator returning elements from the `iterable` and saving
>   a copy of each. When the `iterable` is exhausted, return elements from
>   the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

Use:

```
from itertools import cycle

m, n, k = map(int, input().split())
itr = cycle(range(m, n + 1)) # instantiate a cyclic iterator.

for _ in range(k):
    print(next(itr), end=" ") # print the next element from the iterator
```

OR( without the help of `itertools.cycle` function):

```
m, n, k = map(int, input().split())

counter = 1
while counter < k:
    for n in range(m, n+1):
        print(n, end=' ')
        if counter == k:
            break

        counter += 1
```

If the input is `m=2, n=5, k=15`, then this prints:

```
2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4
```